# Loop through multiple workbooks not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that loops through all the workbooks in a user selected folder and fetch the column names from all the sheets. Note that there may be multiple column names in a single sheet tab. So, the code searches in first column that contains "Product" in it and copies the entire row until last non empty column and pastes them in `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column Names")`.

This code opens the workbook, searches for the text "Product" in each sheet tab, copies the column names and closes the workbook without saving.

I am using the below code to fetch the column names. It works completely fine for only 1 workbook and when the code opens the second workbook, it throws error in the line highlighted.

Anybody please help me to identify where I have done wrong.

```
Option Explicit
Dim i, ShtCnt As Integer
Dim ws, CurSht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim EmpCell As Integer
Dim NonEmpCell As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ThiswblRow, ThiswblRow2 As Long
Dim lCol As Long
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myExtension, filepath, filepathSrc, filepathDest, fileSaveName, filename, Template, TempLocPath, ShtNameRaw, ShtNameTemp, SlrName As String


'Step 1

Public Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInAFolder()
    
'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  
'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        filepath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With
    


'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  filepath = filepath
  If filepath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  TempLocPath = Dir(filepath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While TempLocPath <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=filepath & TempLocPath)
      
    filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(filename).Activate
    
    
'Call Find_Product_in_each_sheet_loop

For ShtCnt = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
'On Error Resume Next
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ShtCnt) 
lRow = ws.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row     -->  Getting error in this line

'Call Find_Product(ws)

For i = 1 To lRow

    lRow = ws.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row

    If InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1), "Product") <> 0 Or InStr(ws.Cells(i, 1), "Model") <> 0 Then
    
    ThiswblRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column Names").Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'Workbook Name
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column names").Range("B" & ThiswblRow) = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    ws.Activate
'Sheet Name
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column names").Range("C" & ThiswblRow) = ActiveSheet.Name
    
    lCol = ws.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    ws.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lCol)).Select

'Column Names

    ws.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lCol)).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column Names").Range("D" & ThiswblRow)
    
    
End If
    
Next i

ThiswblRow = Empty
lRow = Empty

'Next j

Next ShtCnt

    ThiswblRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column Names").Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ThiswblRow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column Names").Range("B100000").End(xlUp).Row
    
'Partner Name

    Workbooks(filename).Sheets("Request Form").Activate
    Workbooks(filename).Sheets("Request Form").Columns(1).Select
    With Selection
    .Find(What:="Partner Name", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
            xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
            xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column Names").Range("A" & ThiswblRow & ":A" & ThiswblRow2)
    End With
    
lRow = Empty
ThiswblRow = Empty
ThiswblRow2 = Empty


'Close Workbook without saving
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
      
'Get next file name
      TempLocPath = Dir
  Loop
  
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Column Names").UsedRange.WrapText = False
  
ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
MsgBox ("Done")
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Make sure you always post the exact error message you get (not an image, the actual text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you have an Excel file in the old format (*.xls). In the old format, sheets had only 64k rows, so using something like `A100000` fails because there is simply no such cell.

Don't use such magic numbers. The total number of rows in a sheet is `ws.rows.count`, and
that works no matter how many rows a sheet has. Change the line to

```
lRow = ws.Cells(ws.rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

or, if you prefer

```
lRow = ws.Range('A' & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
```

P.S.: You should indent your code, the way you presented it is nearly unreadable. I was about to give because it is nearly impossible to tell where loops start and end.

Comment: Thank you so much FunThomas. You nailed it. The code is working perfectly now. And thank you for the feedback. Going forward, I will make sure that I maintain decent indentation.